Ceph dashboard show image usage only for static provisioned volumes
I have a simple question. Why Ceph Dashboard => Block => Images in column "Usage" does not show the size for dynamically created Persistent Volume?
If I create a static volume then, the "Usage" column shows how much space is used. Is this supposed to be the case or am I missing some setting?
If I look at the dynamically created volume via the rbd command, I can see how much is used.
rbd disk-usage app/csi-vol-089f3f73-ca04-4d12-bb58-9ef39cb5d5a1
warning: fast-diff map is not enabled for csi-vol-089f3f73-ca04-4d12-bb58-9ef39cb5d5a1. operation may be slow.
NAME                                          PROVISIONED  USED   
csi-vol-089f3f73-ca04-4d12-bb58-9ef39cb5d5a1      500 GiB  1.1 GiB

Thanks.

I just found a solution/problem. In order to see the "Usage" column in dynamically created volumes. You need to define imageFeatures in StorageClass.
imageFeatures: deep-flatten,exclusive-lock,fast-diff,layering,object-map

